Powershell missing path
I made a NSIS installation program which fire some Powershell commands. I have the following
powershell -ExecutionPolicy Bypass Set-ItemProperty  "HKCU:\Control Panel\International" -Name "sDecimal" -Value "."

I want to change the decimal separator from , to ., but if I the command that way I get an error:

A positional parameter cannot be found that accepts argument 'Panel\International'.

But if I open the Registry Editor, that path exists. Any hints? How can I fix this to use my desired separator?

Disregard this answer, it's wrong as detailed in comments.
See the other answers for correct solutions.
You are in CMD. You should encapsule the powershell command in single quotes, otherwise CMD doesn't realizes it's all the same command.
powershell -ExecutionPolicy Bypass 'Set-ItemProperty -Path "HKCU:\Control Panel\International" -Name "sDecimal" -Value "."'

If you execute your command from cmd.exe, PowerShell will print Set-ItemProperty -Path "HKCU:\Control Panel\International" -Name "sDecimal" -Value "." instead of executing, because it considers the implied -Command argument to be a single-quoted string literal. However, the command would work from PowerShell (but there's rarely a good reason to call the PowerShell CLI from PowerShell). Also, it isn't cmd.exe that's causing the problem with the OP's attempt, but PowerShell itself.

Thanks for updating. My guess is that @Alberto tried to run his command in PowerShell, not in cmd.exe, and there your solution does work, as noted (although using a script block ({ ... }) is the better alternative). He probably accepted your answer because he found an effective solution in it, even though its framing and explanation was incorrect.


tl;dr

To call your command from PowerShell, enclose it in { ... } (i.e. in a script block) to avoid your problem:
# From PowerShell
powershell -ExecutionPolicy Bypass { Set-ItemProperty  "HKCU:\Control Panel\International" -Name "sDecimal" -Value "." }


In addition to avoiding escaping headaches, this approach is preferable due to preserving type fidelity, within limits; see this answer for details.

Also note that calling the PowerShell CLI from PowerShell is rarely needed, except if you truly need to run your command in a separate process (which introduces overhead and has type-fidelity limitations); in the case at hand, you could simply make the Set-ItemProperty call directly in your session.



From outside PowerShell, you must escape " chars. that form part of the PowerShell command to execute as \"
:: From cmd.exe / a batch file / any other context OUTSIDE PowerShell
powershell -ExecutionPolicy Bypass Set-ItemProperty \"HKCU:\Control Panel\International\" -Name sDecimal -Value .



Read on for an explanation and details; while it is focused on calls from outside PowerShell, it also explains why your original command fails inside PowerShell too.

As explained in detail in this answer, " characters that you want to pass through to the (here implied) -Command parameter of PowerShell (Core) 7 must be escaped, in the simplest form as \":
Unescaped " are removed by PowerShell during its initial command-line parsing, which explains your symptom; that is, PowerShell executed the following, which predictably fails:
# !! Fails, because the HKCU: path contains spaces, but now isn't quoted.
Set-ItemProperty HKCU:\Control Panel\International -Name sDecimal -Value .

Thus, one solution is to enclose the HKCU: path in \"...\" (note that the -Name and -Value arguments don't require quoting, so none is used):
:: From OUTSIDE PowerShell, e.g. from cmd.exe / a batch file.
:: Note the \"...\" around the HKCU: path
powershell -ExecutionPolicy Bypass Set-ItemProperty \"HKCU:\Control Panel\International\" -Name sDecimal -Value .

Note:

Strictly speaking, what is inside \"...\" is subject to whitespace normalization; that is, runs of two or more spaces would become a single space.

This is isn't a problem here, but see the linked answer for solutions in cases where it could be.



An alternative is to use '...' quoting, i.e. a verbatim (single-quoted) string:
:: From OUTSIDE PowerShell, e.g. from cmd.exe / a batch file.
:: Note the '...' around the HKCU: path
powershell -ExecutionPolicy Bypass Set-ItemProperty 'HKCU:\Control Panel\International' -Name sDecimal -Value .

Note:

This is syntactically easier (' chars. have no special meaning during the initial command-line parsing) and may also be conceptually preferable, because it treats the content of the string verbatim, whereas the content of "..." (escaped as \"...\"), i.e. of an expandable (double-quoted) string is subject to expansion (string interpolation).

Caveat: Do NOT enclose the entire command in '...' when calling PowerShell from the outside (including from cmd.exe):[1] PowerShell will treat it as a verbatim string literal and simply print its contents.


On the flip side, given that cmd.exe doesn't recognize '...' strings, any cmd.exe metacharacters such as & inside such strings would then have to be individually ^-escaped (e.g., 'a ^& b').
See the linked answer for alternatives.



[1] This wouldn't happen when calling from PowerShell, because PowerShell translates '...' strings into "..." strings behind the scenes, but then again there's rarely a good reason to call the PowerShell CLI from a PowerShell session and in cases where it is truly called for, using { ... } is the better alternative, as noted.
